# Define a set of iterators of set in c++

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set, std

I am trying to define a set in which elements are iterators of another set. In detail, I have defined the following set, but when I want to insert an element into the set, c++ doesn't allow. How I construct a set of iterators?

```
set<set<set<int>>::iterator> s;
set<set<int>> s1;
set<int> s2;
s2.insert(2);
s1.insert(s2);
s.insert(s1.begin());
```

Comment: This is getting into [XY Problem territory](http://xyproblem.info/).  Why do you need such a thing as a `set` of iterators?

Comment: *"c++ doesn't allow"* - the ensuing, complete, verbatim error message should be [included in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59339846/edit)

Comment: Now try inserting s1.begin(), instead. After all that is your clear intent here.

Comment: *"How I construct a set of iterators?"* - You don't, at least not with the default comparator type. Assuming you fix the posted code for proper types (`s.insert(s1.begin())` your build will fail regardless. Set iterators are standard bidirectional (they support increment, advance, etc). They do not support ordered comparison (i.e. the default `std::set<Type>` comparator, `std::less<Type>` defaults to `operator <`, which set iterators do not expose). If you really want this, and frankly i'm pressed to see how it is useful, you need a custom comparator type, and I caution taking that road.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I understand from your comments that I should define a compare function of two iterators.

Comment: I don't see why the downvotes for this question.  The OP has a set of sets s1. Suppose that the sets inside s1 are very large. Now he wants to create a set s with elements from s1. Instead of creating another set of sets, which may be expensive, the goal is to create a set of "pointers" (iterators) to sets in s1.

Comment: @Mat of course s2 is not a set of sets. In this example, s2 is a set of int, and he puts s2 inside s1. So s1 is the set of sets. And s is the prospective set of iterators to sets inside s1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the requirements for putting something into a set?

You need it to be copyable (broadly), and you need a comparison function that imposes a strict weak ordering. (the default is `<`).  Since `set::iterator` does not provide such an operator, you'll have to write one yourself.

Doing so efficiently may prove to be a challenge.

Comment: Do you have any idea about defining the comparison function? Each iterator point to a set, maybe it is better to define the comparison function of sets.

Comment: What does it mean for one iterator to be ordered before another? That's the question to be answered. _[Note: there doesn't have to be one unique answer]_